# using semantic ui with angular 2

Tags: angular, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-angular

I am new to angular world and i have to design a website.I have to use angular 2 for my project and I went through a lot of online ui-framweworks and found semantic-ui to be nice.But the problem is that they don't have limited angular components defined in the angular version of their site(ng-semantic) so i decided to go with the usual old method ie by including .min.css and .min.js files in the angular-cli.json file.So my question is is this a good approach or am i gonna design something which is not in usual practice and will have to rewrite my code again..Please advice me if i am going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. You can use the CSS framework but you won't be able to execute dynamically changing components like

> drop-down

or

> select

which need java script to be implemented. For these you can use the ng-Semantic UI framework or Prime-ng or similar ones. There are many plugins available on GitHub too that can easily be used for drop down and other purposes so no need to worry.